# How to filter a random string generator from certain results

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Is it possible to add a filter to a random string gen so that it cannot produce certain strings. I am using this to create unique codes for my users and I need to make sure that a code is not assigned more than once.

This is how I am generating random alphanumeric

```
func randomString(length: Int) -> String {
    let letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
    return String((0..<length).map{ _ in letters.randomElement()! })
}
```

Comment: Presumably you have an Array or Set of previously-used strings. Do you know how to see if the result appears in that array or set?

Comment: Are you generating all the codes at one time or do you maintain a list of generated codes, or are you trying to do this without maintaining a list of issued codes? What scale are you looking at (how many codes do you need to generate in total, and at what speed?) What kind of length do you need these to be? (do they need to easily typed?) Do they need to be permanently non-repeating, or just within some period? Is a single repeat catastrophic or easily resolvable?

Comment: @RobNapier, Everytime a user is created in firebase, I want to assign a special code to their document. In the process of assigning that document, I want to make sure that the the code I generated for them is not taken. The codes are 9 charachters long, the checking if the code is valid is at Sign up of the user. The filtering is just one approach but the basic idea is to generate a unique code for each user and store it in their firebase document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as your strings is long enough, your current scheme is already everything you need. You can make collisions of random values arbitrarily unlikely. This is the basis of UUIDv4. There are just so many possible values (>10^36) that no one will ever pick a duplicate. If you can use UUIDs directly, I recommend that. It's well supported.

If you need to use letters and numbers, then you can do the same thing, though.

UUID gets that by having 122 bits of randomness. You have 62 symbols. To get 122 bits of randomness, you need ~20 characters. If that's ok, you're done. Generate 20 character random codes and I promise, they will never collide. For each character you shorten it by, the likelihood of a collision goes up. This is called a [Birthday Attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack). Back-of-the-envelope, you expect (50% likely) your first collision after `1.25*sqrt(H)` where H is the number of values you can encode.

So for 10 characters, you expect your first collision around 1.25*sqrt(62^10) or around 1 billion documents. If your total number of documents is a few orders of magnitude smaller than that (a few million or fewer), then 10 characters will be fine. Other scales can be similar calculated.

But if you can, just use UUID.

Comment: So 9 characters is safe? I'm not aiming for any more users greater than 1,000

Comment: Absolutely. The chances of a single collision on 1000 9-character random values is somewhere around `1000^2 / 2*62^9` or 1 in 27 billion.